# Why are links color so light in the actual question?

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

When you write a question SO, right below it you see what you are typing. If you place in a link you will see the link turning into a blue color. The blue color is quite visible to the eye.

However once I'm done with the question and question is published, the blue color of the link doesn't have the same good contrast as when you are typing your question. Is this color difference intentional? Or this a bug?

To me it seems more like a bug as the color on the final written question is slightly lighter and harder to spot if the linked text is something small as 'here' or 'link'. It becomes more visible if it has more characters.

## EDIT2:

The color change is because the links have been visited before. Yet the only bug now is that the visited links aren't visible enough if the link doesn't have much characters and the contrast between a visited and non-visited link isn't enough for the average eye to distinguish. So a good solution would be a better color contrast!

## EDIT1:

**Preview example—when writing answer/question**
[image]

**actual finished written**
[image]

Comment: Must be a CSS bug from a "fix" that was applied.  I just started noticing this today.  I can confirm the link looks good in the preview pane in the edit.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not sure, but I think I have seen this for a long time now!

Comment: That is possible.  I just noticed it today.

Comment: Screenshot for comparison? Because I don't see it :/ Links in both questions and answers are still quite blue to me - the same blue as in the preview pane when writing a question. Just to be sure it isn't the browser cache I tried in a second browser I never touch and the same deal there. Makes me wonder if it is platform specific. I'm on MacOS, tried in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I'm seeing the same as @Gimby, using Firefox on Windows.

Comment: @Gimby see my screenshot I'm using chrome on Mac El Captian

Comment: @Stijn see my screenshot

Comment: Well I had to squint but I see it too :) I see two shades actually; links I have already visited are the slightly darker blue you describe as having less contrast, links I haven't visited yet are the lighter sharper blue. Apparently in edit review mode, there is no CSS style for visited links perhaps?

Comment: @Gimby HAH. Thanks for pointing that out. I just tried a new question from someone and the color color contrast is good. Once you click on the link, the color contrast changes. Which is understandable. I wasn't thinking of that. The only thing is the CSS visited color is terrible to the eye!

Comment: Related: [Make visited links a bit more visible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269539/make-visited-links-a-bit-more-visible) and [Visited links should be more visible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible)

Comment: @Gimby I just voted for it to be closed! :|